# Is it posssible to find an x/y coordinate without Angles? i need this for a target locator in a Scratch Program

Tags: triangulation, mit-scratch

My scratch project:https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/657133771

i need a triangulation/trilateralation equation for a target locator. otherwise the tank is just stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Distance Formula (Pythagorean Theorem) to calculate the distance between points. Simply use:
[image: distance formulat]

distance = sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 )

Answer (score 0):

Make the x and y change at the same time. It will give an angle effect, and your sprite does not have to turn. Not exactly a formula, but if you match up the x and y changes in the right way, you get different angles.